# Having arrays as function input and output in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, function, fortran

I have a function which I want to do some mathematical operations inside of it, on an array which I will input to it as an array, and then the function will return an array as the output. This is the code I've been trying out but I can't seem to get it working!

```
program solve_linear
implicit none

    real, allocatable :: A( :,: ) ,B(:),XX(:)
    integer :: M
    real, allocatable :: X(:)

    M=3
    allocate(B(M),XX(M),X(1:M))

    B(1)=7
    B(2)=4
    B(3)=-10

    XX=X(B,M)

end program solve_linear

function X(B,M)
implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: M
    real, dimension(M), intent(in) :: B
    real, dimension(M) :: X
    integer :: i

    do i=1,M
        X(i)=B(i)**2
    end do

end function
```

My main problem is using the output of the function in my program code, which you can see in the XX=X(B,M). What I want to do here, is that I want a function that gets the array B as the input, and multiplies each array element by itself and returning the resulting array as the output of the function. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Basically, put your function into a module, use the module and delete `real, allocatable :: X(:)` and then it should work fine. You can also put the function after `contains` in the main program.

Comment: And remember, always tell us what is wrong, which error messages or wrong results you got (see [ask]).

Comment: Also remove `X` from the allocate statement.